# Pass variable to html frame

Tags: html, frame

I have a django app having

views.py

`//some code`
`render(request, 'showmain.html',{"info": info})`

and showmain.html

```
<html>
<frameset rows = "70%,*">  
<frame src="showinfo.html">  
</frameset>  
</html>
```

I want to pass the data in info to showinfo.html.
How can this be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812716/how-do-i-pass-variables-in-django-through-the-url

Comment: using js might help http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471111/A-Quick-Tutorial-on-JavaScript-Variable-Passing.htm