# Django looking for variable i can use in object.filter

Tags: python, django

I am using a for loop to get data from a database and a html page shows every db entry as a different card, with a button under it. If i click the button, it should show me a html page with more information. On that page i use `<a href="receptinfo?{{recepten.name}}" class="btn btn-info knop">Meer Info</a>` and this works. The url shows : localhost/receptinfo?Babi%20pangang

In views.py try to setup a filter for objects.filter( ) which uses a variable.
I tried: recepten = Recept_Info.objects.filter(name='{{recepten,name}}'), it doesn't show any errors, but also it shows no data.
When i try: recepten = Recept_Info.objects.filter(name={{recepten,name}}), i get UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment error.

If i write: recepten = Recept_Info.objects.filter(name='Babi pangang') it works.

My question is how can i use the name i get from {{recepten.name}} as object.filter(......)

**recept.html**

```
<div class="container">
{% for recepten in recepten %}
<div class='row'>
<div class="data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="200">
  <div class="card-deck">    
    <div class="card">    
      <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">{{recepten.name}}</h4>
          <ul>
          <li><p class="card-text">Menugang: {{recepten.menugang}}</p></li>
          <li><p class="card-text">Keuken: {{recepten.keuken}}</p></li>
          <li><p class="card-text">Bereidingstijd: {{recepten.bereidingstijd}} min.</p></li>
          <li><p class="card-text">Personen: {{recepten.aantal_personen}}</p></li>
          <li><p class="card-text">Vegetarisch : {{recepten.Vegetarisch |yesno:"Ja,Nee" }}</p></li>



          
          <ul>
            
      </div>
      
      <a href="receptinfo?{{recepten.name}}" class="btn btn-info knop">Meer Info</a>
    </div>
  </div>
 {% endfor %} 
  </div>
</div>  
<div class="end">
</div>
```

**Views.py**

```
def receptinfo(request):
  
  recepten = Recept_Info.objects.filter(name='{{recepten,name}}')
  return render(request, 'receptinfo.html', {'recepten': recepten})
def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: You should make one URL in urls.py and redirect to views. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812716/how-do-i-pass-variables-in-django-through-the-url/12812996

Comment: I am not sure if this is what i need and how to achieve that. I used the url 
<a href="receptinfo?{{recepten.name}}" class="btn btn-info knop">Meer Info</a> like this to see if it would show up. It did, so when i press the button there should be a variable from recepten.name because it does show up in the url. That variable i want to take from the page and use in views.py as the variable i could use in the filter.

Comment: What i did try and also gave no errors but no output is:

<a href="receptinfo?id={{recepten.name}}" class="btn btn-info knop">Meer Info</a> and in the views.py i put request.GET.get('id')    recepten = Recept_Info.objects.filter(name='id')

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figured it out.

The button in HTML

```
<a href="receptinfo?id={{recepten.name}}" class="btn btn-info knop">Meer Info</a>
```

And in Views.py

```
 naam = request.GET.get('id')
  recepten = Recept_Info.objects.filter(name=naam)
```